# Does the tangent line really touch a single point?

Tags: calculus, geometry, derivatives, graphing-functions

The principle of the theory of the tangent to a curve is that it is the limit of the secant when the two intersection points, one of them approaches the other, I mean in Calculus I. I intend to prove that for every function $f$ differentiable on an interval $I$ and a number $a$ from that interval, the equation : $f’(a)(x-a)+f(a)=f(x)$ accepts $a$ as a double solution. Can I? Or prove that their intersection is a double point.

Comment: Try $a=0$ and $f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2\sin(1/x),& x\neq0\\0,& x=0\end{cases}$.

Comment: @تقي الدين If you take $f(x)=x\sqrt{x}$ and $a=0$ you can see that it is not true. $f(0)=0$, $f'(0)=0$, however $0=0(x-0)+0=f(x)$ has $x=0$ as a solution of order $1$. You can't divide by $x^2$.

Comment: What do you mean by "double solution"?

Comment: Okay, no, you can't prove that.  There are not two points of crossing.  You are taking the limit of a "family" of lines with two crossings.  The limit itself is not one of these lines and the point of tangency is just a single point.  (There might be other points but they are incidental and not pertinant to the problem.)

Comment: @zipirovich I am substantially more confused by OP asking about a "double solution" than I am by SimplyBeautifulArt's small mistake....

Comment: @Chris I think the OP means that the line $m(x-a) + f(a) = f(x)$ where $m = \frac {f(x_0) - f(a)}{x_0 - a}$ will have two solutions $x = a$ and $x = x_0$, will $f'(a)(x-a) + f(a)= f(x)$ will have two solutions at $x = a$ and $x = a$ where $a$ is a "double root" in the same sense as $x=2$ is a "double root" of the polynomial $(x-2)^2(x+3)$.  It doesn't really work that way though.  ("double root" is not actually defined and meaningful to start with.)

Comment: @Chris: But there's a huge difference between them: the OP **asks** a question, while the other one **answers** it. It's quite natural that people who ask questions have some confusion -- otherwise, they wouldn't have any reason to ask anything, would they? But providing an "answer" that's outright wrong is no small thing. Not to mention that this mistake is not small at all.

Comment: @zipirovich Oops, my bad the previous statement holds for functions that are convex or concave on interval near the point in question.

Comment: @user463383 Yeah, my bad.  See above comment for when a tangent line crosses a function locally once.

Comment: A repeated root is for a double point at point of tangency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f$ is differentiable on an interval $(b, c)$, then for any $b \lt a \lt c$ such that $f''(a)$ exists, we have, after an application of L'Hôpital's rule, $$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow a} \frac{f'(a)(x - a) + f(a) - f(x)}{(x - a)^2} = \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow a} \frac{f'(a) - f'(x)}{2(x - a)} = -\frac{1}{2}f''(a).$$

Thus $a$ is a zero of order larger than or equal to $2$ in this case (note that it could even be larger than $2$ if the $f''(a) = 0$).

The counterexamples given in the comments above have functions that are not twice-differentiable at the point where the limit is taken so this argument does not work for them. One could also come up with functions where the solution $a$ is a $n$-th order zero for an arbitrary $n \gt 1$.

For example $f(x) = x^5$ has the equation $f'(0)(x - 0) + f(0) - f(x) = -x^5 = 0$ with $0$ as a solution with multiplicity $5$.

Comment: I am not too familiar with this, but I believe there is a general concept of "intersection number" in algebraic geometry that generalizes in a sense the multiplicity of the intersection of two curves. Someone else might have something to say about this.